# Solr, cast an array of strings to an array of payloads

Tags: solr

I have a solrcloud connected to a mongo database whit mongoconnector. I want to use payload functionality in solr, but I can't cast it correct. I managed to import it as a string like:

```
 "topCategoryScoreList":["2107|510",
          "1225|940"],
```

and after that whit a simple copyfield:

```
<copyField source = "topCategoryScoreList" dest = "topCategoryPayload"/>
```

the field is define as:

```
<field name="topCategoryPayload" type="payload" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

and payload type:

```
<fieldtype name="payload" stored="true" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" 
      delimiter='|' encoder="float"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

but it didn't work. What I also tried is to write an updateRequestProcessorChain

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="payload">
       <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
       <lst name="source">
                    <str name="fieldName">topCategoryScoreList</str>
       </lst>
                    <str name="dest">topCategoryPayload</str>
       </processor>
       <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="fieldName">topCategoryPayload</str>
            <str name="delimiter">|</str>
       </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

but that also note worked. What I managed to solve is to concatenate latitude and longitude in one location field (but those are not multiValued fields). 
Should I write a plugin for that? Or any other ideas?
Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

probably you have to simplify and try:

```
   <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">  
                <str name="fieldName">topCategoryScoreList</str>
                <str name="dest">topCategoryPayload</str>
   </processor>

<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```